# mysql - query with multiple left joins takes too long

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to fetch data with a query which has left joins on multiple tables. The query returns 4132 rows and takes 4.55 sec duration, 31.30 sec fetch in `mysql workbench`. I even tried to execute it from `php` but that takes the same amount of time.

```
SELECT
                aa.bams_id AS chassis_bams_id, aa.hostname AS chassis_hostname, 
    aa.rack_number AS chassis_rack, aa.serial_number AS chassis_serial, aa.site_id AS chassis_site_id,
    cb.bay_number, cb.bsn AS serial_number_in_bay,
CASE
                WHEN a_a.bams_id IS NULL THEN 'Unknown'
                ELSE a_a.bams_id
END AS blade_bams_id,
                a_a.hostname AS blade_hostname, a_s.description AS blade_status, a_a.manufacturer AS blade_manufacturer, a_a.model AS blade_model,
                a_a.bookable_unit_id AS blade_bookable_unit_id, a_a.rack_number AS blade_rack_number, a_a.manufactured_date AS blade_manufactured_date,
                a_a.support_expired_date AS blade_support_expired_date, a_a.site_id AS blade_site_id
FROM all_assets aa
                LEFT JOIN manufacturer_model mm ON aa.manufacturer = mm.manufacturer AND aa.model = mm.model
                LEFT JOIN chassis_bays cb ON aa.bams_id = cb.chassis_bams_id
                LEFT JOIN all_assets a_a ON cb.bsn = a_a.serial_number
                LEFT JOIN asset_status a_s ON a_a.status=a_s.status
WHERE mm.hardware_type = 'chassis';
```

These are the definition of tables being used:

[image]

Output of `EXPLAIN`:

[image]

The query fetches data of each blade in each chassis.
**Executed the same query on other systems and it takes only 5 seconds to fetch the result.**

**How do I optimize this query ?**

**Update (resolved)**

Added indexes as suggested by experts here.
Below is the execution plan after adding indexes.

[image]

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN`; Add indices to the join columns.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen added result of `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: This is not the "definition of the tables", its a screenshot of womething which lists the attributes in the tables. There are lots of posts here about slow mysql queries - please go read some of them, note what's mising from the ones which get downvoted and closed, what is present in those which are upvoted and answered and if you are still unable to resolve the problem yourself apply what you've learnt to your question.

Comment: You have no indices, so go and add them.

Comment: If possible then go with ***`INNER JOIN`***,if it's not make any impact on your business logic.And if it's make any impact then go with **`INDICES`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create indexes, non indexed reads are slower than index reads.

To determine exactly what is causing you slow performance, the best tool
is to use the "query plan analyzer":

Have a look here:
[mySql performance explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-performance-explain.html)

Try creating indexes on the most obvious reads that will take place.Look at the fields that play a role when you join and also your where clause. If you have indexes on those fields your performance should increase, if non index reads were taking place.

If this is still a problem it is best to see how mySQL is fetching the data,
sometimes restructuring your data or even maybe altering the way you are queuing
can give you better results.

eg. Create index's for: aa.manufacturer_model, aa.manufacturer, aa.model and mm.hardware_type

Comment: added indexes and now it works fine. takes 0.062 sec to fetch teh data. I've also updated my question description with execution plan after adding indexes.

Answer (score 0):

#### Similar Problem

I had a `user`s table with many relations to other tables: **21 `LEFT JOIN`s**.
The query not only took long, it also crashed my NodeJS server with a "JS heap out of memory" ...

#### My Solution

My Solution was to translate some of the `left join`s to a `sub query` that uses `JSON_ARRAYAGG` and `GROUP BY`

#### Notes:

- I previously tried changing the left join to a right join but that resulted with an "Empty set".
- Personly I couldn't make it in 1 TypeORM QueryBuilder so I have 2 queries for getting a `user`'s data.

#### My solution's code

- The code is quite specific to my needs, but the general idea is to change the "left join" to a `sub query` with a `group by` and a `JSON_ARRAYAGG` if that suits you. (Then JSON.parse() of course. (JS))
- notice: It's TypeORM's QueryBuilder syntax, but I think it's easy to understand and translate to a pure MySQL query
- user === therapist

I had a many to many relation. That means 2 `LEFT JOIN`s

prev:

```sql
LEFT JOIN `therapists_treatment_qualifications` `therapist_treatmentQualifications` ON `therapist_treatmentQualifications`.`user_id` = `therapist`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `treatment_qualification` `treatmentQualifications` ON `treatmentQualifications`.`id` = `therapist_treatmentQualifications`.`treatment_qualification_id`
```

solution:

```
// "query 1":
const therapist = await this.therapistRepository.createQueryBuilder('therapist');
    .leftJoinAndSelect('therapist.languages', 'languages')
    .where('therapist.id = :therapistId', { therapistId })
    .getOne();

// "query 2":
const therapist_moreFieldsStringified = await this.therapistRepository.createQueryBuilder('therapist')
    .select([]) // otherwise will select therapist table columns
    .addSelect(qb => (
        qb.select(`JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT("name", treatmentQualifications.name, "id", treatmentQualifications.id))`, "treatment_qualifications")
            .from("therapists_treatment_qualifications", "therapist_treatmentQualifications")
            .innerJoin("treatment_qualification", "treatmentQualifications", "treatmentQualifications.id = therapist_treatmentQualifications.treatment_qualification_id")
            .where("therapist_treatmentQualifications.user_id = therapist.id")
            .groupBy("therapist_treatmentQualifications.user_id")
    ), "treatmentQualifications")
... // more .addSelect(..^same as above^..) if needed

    .getRawOne();

// add fields of "query 2" to "query 1"`s therapist
for (const fieldName in therapist_moreFieldsStringified) {
    const stringifiedValue = therapist_moreFieldsStringified[fieldName]
    therapist[fieldName] = JSON.parse(stringifiedValue);
}
```